# Forwarding data member of an rvalue calls move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Why is the `Foo` data member moved in this context?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "move!" << std::endl; }
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "copy!" << std::endl; }
};
struct Bar
{
    Foo foo{};
};
template<typename T>
void forward_data_member(T&& bar)
{
    const auto foo = std::forward<Foo>(bar.foo);
}
int main()
{
    Bar bar{};
    forward_data_member(bar); // move!
    return 0;
}
```

I've checked with the debugger - the type of bar is deduced to be an lvalue reference when `forward_data_member` is called here.

I would assume that a data member of an lvalue reference would also be an lvalue. In fact, it says here that a data member is **always** an rvalue reference - so I really don't understand this behaviour!
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Any help much appreciated! :-)

Comment: `forward` is a conditional move, with the condition being "template argument is not an lvalue reference". So it never makes sense to use `forward` with a fixed template parameter, since you might as well use `move` (or nothing) directly. In this case, you probably want `std::forward<T>(bar).foo`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks! :-)